# Get address as is for URL

Tags: php, variables, mod-rewrite

I'm using mod rewrite to rewrite some dynamic php links.

Such as `file.php?id=1` equals `/file/1/`

Are there any special PHP functions or similar that I can use to get `/file/1/` instead of `file.php?id=1` ?

Something like `$_SERVER` which will read the mod rewrite instead of the PHP link.

Comment: Whats your.htaccess look like?

Comment: Try a `var_dump($_SERVER)`, then come back if you're still not sure :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/c492b